# Angular Select Value only 2 way Binding Not working

Tags: angularjs

I am trying a very simple thing angular select ng-options binding I only intend to Bind the value and a service will populate the value into my model. the problem is the drop down not selecting the correct item

```
        <pre>
    <select class=" form-control" ng-model="Incident.Language" 
ng-options="lan.Value as lan.Label  for lan in model.DomainData['Language'].FieldValues">
<option value="0">--Select--</option>
</select>
</pre>
```

Comment: do you have any console error? and some extra information like your options in array, etc. If possible provide a plunker

Comment: I have no console errors i can see the drop down with value it doesn't set the correct value when i Incident.Language in service return call

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. Our Service returns the data with Incident.Language as Integer and when binding value is string so the equality was failing